# Is it possible to perform a Breadth First Search with an Array of Neighbors?

Tags: python, list, graph, networkx, graph-theory

The input of the program is this:

```
1 2
2 3
2 5
5 1
3 4
4 5
4 6
```

The first number represents the vertex one, second number represents vertex 2. This means there is an edge connecting the two vertices, meaning they are neighbours.
1[
My question is, is it possible to perform a BFS using only a list of neighbours? Or would I need to convert the data into a graph?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to go about this would be to build a graph, and use the available algorithms. In NetworkX foe instance, you have a set of basic algorithms for *breadth-first* searching the nodes of a graph in [`nx.algorithms.traversal`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/traversal.html). So you could do:

```
s = '''1 2
2 3
2 5
5 1
3 4
4 5
4 6'''

l = [i.split() for i in s.splitlines()]
```

Then build a graph from the list of edges:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.from_edgelist(l)
```

And use the available methods from the mentioned module such as iterating over edges in a breadth-first-search starting at source:

```
list(nx.algorithms.traversal.breadth_first_search.bfs_edges(G, '2'))
# [('2', '1'), ('2', '3'), ('2', '5'), ('3', '4'), ('4', '6')]
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to perform a BFS using only a list of neighbours?

list of neighbours is perfect input for the BFS problems.

(we call it adjacency list)

converting the list into graph or not is a matter of interpretation.

you can code BFS with the list, using vectors or some other simple data structures,

without explicitly converting the list into some 'graph class' or something.

but it will be easy for you to draw a conceptual graph in order to verify inputs and outputs.